# How does a program figures out type of encoding before reading a file?

Tags: file, utf-8, character-encoding

I am new to programming and trying to get my head around encodings. Till now my idea about encoding is that each character corresponds to a code point, which then is converted to a binary representation depending on the kind of encoding we choose.

Now when a program tries to read this file, how does it know about the kind of encoding used for that file? Does a program by default uses a type of encoding, Eg. UTF-8? If that is the case assume a program that uses ascii by default, then will it read a UTF-8 file incorrectly, given that there are characters which doesn't belong to ascii standard? Or will it figure out somehow that this is not ascii and read it accordingly? If so how?

My second guess is information about encoding may be embedded in the file itself which is figured out by the program. If so how does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

**In general there is no way to recognize the character set of a file**

Today's programs and browsers are mostly based on UTF-8. Some editors even write a byte order mark (`0xEF` `0xBB` `0xBF` to mark the format) at the beginning of the file to remember the encoding. There are some invalid character codes in Unicode, which can be used to identify other encodings:

First of all, each character in UTF-8 must be of the form `0xxxxxxx` where `x` is an arbitrary bit. There are three exceptions:

- a byte `10xxxxxx` must follow  a byte `110xxxxx`
- two bytes `10xxxxxx` must follow a byte `1110xxxx`
- three bytes `10xxxxxx` must follow a byte `11110xxx`

For further explanations see for example  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

On websites (i.e. in HTML) the coding is specified separately using tags like

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no way to know the encoding. Especially on past, a lot of encoding seems similar (just with different accented characters).

For many internet protocol, there is a way to communicate the encoding, so that the program knows the *supposed* encoding. You see this with email, ftp, http. Also in databases, now one should specify the encoding (and possibly the language, for sorting strings).

But for normal text file, it was difficult. Many program try to get new line correctly (*new-line* [unix] vs. *line-feed* together with *carriage-return* [ASCII], and sometime just *carriage-return* [old Mac]) [Note: *new-line* and *line-feed* are the same character].

Now we are in a much more standardized world, so encodings are easier. Often we have such algorithm:

- Check first bytes, if you see a correct BOF (3 different way to start a file), you will interpret it as UTF-8, UTF-16LE, or UTF-16BE.
- On non-Windows machines (or on Windows but for web files):

  - Assume it is a UTF-8. If it is ok, it should be UTF-8 (maybe just try the first block of characters [e.g. 4096]). UTF-8 has a very strict sequence of characters (and forbidden characters), so a non-UTF-8 file should usually fail UTF-8 test. Note: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so you will decode ASCII files correctly in this point
  - Else assume Latin-1 or a "Windows ANSI" encoding on other Windows code pages (e.g. from your system: probably who wrote the file is from your same language). Latin-1 is a sub-set of "Windows ANSI" (and of other windows code pages, and most characters should be ok.
- On Windows machines: go to the above point [UTF-8, with fall-back] if you field/niche/settings could expect usually UTF-8

  - else: assume Latin-1 or a suitable "Windows ANSI" encoding. Windows try to add BOM to UTF-8
- In any case, one should allows user to specify the encoding (e.g. in case the above algorithm fail).

For Asian languages, there are other algorithms, usually checking frequent bytes and group of bytes.

Note: there are also libraries which help detecting language, but for sure you have seen programs and browsers to fail detecting the right encoding. This is inevitable.

Now Unicode is becoming the standard way, and "Windows ANSI" replaced most of all encoding for Latin scripts, so the task it is easy, but if you need to convert old files.

Comment: So would it be right for me to assume that finding encoding is kind of making an assumption in advance about the encoding type of file and then validating it by going through the file , either by detecting some sort of signature or by guessing through the content, till it finds the right one? The program has no idea in advance about encoding type?

Comment: Yes. In past people were linked with own computer or eventually with some systems. "File of IBM xx system", etc. Also most files where on same language, so in East Europe you will find some encoding, on Nordic countries an other, then Western, Cyrillic, Greek, etc. Web tried to solve this, using mostly ASCII, and using escapes (entities) for symbols and accented characters. But still there were a lot of bad pages. Encoding is not yet entirely solved, but you still see a lot of wrong assumptions (with "unknown symbol"). Check your question's tags: you see a lot of q. about wrong encoding.